# Representing infinity in physics calculations

Tags: c++, collision, game-physics, infinity, numeric-limits

I'm currently writing some functions to deal with elastic collisions in C++. I've hit a stumbling block when dealing with a moving object colliding with an immovable object because the calculations require the immovable object to have infinite mass.

I am aware that `std::numeric_limits` provides `infinity()` but I'm not sure it is entirely useful in this case since, as far as I'm aware, this is just the max number possible in the floating point representation. In the following code, if `aabb_obj` has a mass equal to `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` it seems that every calculation that uses it is either going to result in `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` or `0`.

```
double t;
if (intersect_moving_circle_aabb(circle_obj, aabb_obj, t))
{
    circle_obj->position += circle_obj->velocity * t;

    vec2 closest_point;
    closest_pt_point_aabb(circle_obj->position, aabb_obj, closest_point);

    vec2 n = (closest_point - circle_obj->position).normalized();

    double a = dot_product(circle_obj->velocity, n);

    double p = (2.0 * a) / (circle_obj->mass + aabb_obj->mass);

    circle_obj->velocity = circle_obj->velocity - p * aabb_obj->mass * n;
}
```

This is for a game so the results don't need to be 100% physically accurate, just 'good enough'. What is the recommended way for representing infinity in such calculations? Do I just pick an arbitrarily high number?

Comment: A useful approximation would be to give an object an "immovable" property that you check before attempting to update its vectors. Also, you can set the object's mass to `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` to aid in the calculation of the movable object's vectors. This would work reasonably well if you wanted to switch to integral types too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With IEEE floats, the two infinities are already treated specially by the hardware, along with the Not-A-Number values (NANs). And they obey the normal math rules:

```
1/0 = +inf
+inf + x = +inf
-inf + +inf = NAN
x/+inf = 0
0*+inf = NAN
...
```

Now you can check your code to see what happens if you plug in `+inf` for one of the masses: This will yield a value of `p = 0`, and in the following line `p * aabb_obj->mass` will either yield `0` if `aabb_obj->mass` is finite, or `NAN` if it's infinite. The later case is the one you need to avoid, because the `NAN` will be propagated through the other operations, yielding `circle_obj->velocity = NAN`.

Comment: Your explanation of floating point infinity helped me understand the bizarre results I was getting from my code. It was in the end easier to just remove mass from the calculations. I have added an answer to explain how I eventually solved the problem but I have accepted yours because it was most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would make the fact that some objects are immovable explicit in my code. As in, instead of plugging in values into one generic formula that *should* prevent some objects from moving, have different branches of execution for two movable objects colliding vs a movable and unmovable object colliding.

Also, if accuracy is not a huge concern, use `float`s instead of `double`s. :)

Comment: In the end I added a branch to the code to deal explicitly with immovable objects. Turns out the calculations are actually easier than for 2 movable objects with differing mass. I'm not sure what benefit switching to float would give me on modern x86 hardware. Though I will look into it in the future, I'm not in a hurry to prematurely optimize things.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question was supposed to calculate the rebound velocity for a circular moving object when it collided with an immovable AABB object. A perfectly immovable object should in theory have infinite mass but as can be seen, representing this in floating point causes the calculations to produce a vector of (NaN, NaN).

In the end I opted for an explicit check for infinite mass which simplified the code.

An immovable object cannot gain momentum from a collision, and because of [Conservation of Momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#Conservation) the moving object cannot lose any momentum. This means the mass of both objects is irrelevant to the calculations because the magnitude of the moving object's velocity will not change, only the direction will change.

Understanding this allowed me to reduce the code to simply reflecting the velocity vector about the collision normal:

```
double t;
if (aabb_obj->mass == std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()
    && intersect_moving_circle_aabb(circle_obj, aabb_obj, t))
{
    circle_obj->position += circle_obj->velocity * t;

    vec2 closest_point;
    closest_pt_point_aabb(circle_obj->position, aabb_obj, closest_point);

    vec2 n = (closest_point - circle_obj->position).normalized();

    circle_obj->velocity = circle_obj->velocity - 2.0 * dot_product(circle_obj->velocity, n) * n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> as far as I'm aware, this is just the max number possible in the floating point representation.

Sure it is, for IEEE floating point numbers cannot represent anything greater than infinity. In the meantime, this is truly infinity and you can use it safely.